# How to move features from one layer to another?

Tags: qgis

I have a polygon which belongs to a layer and I need to move it to another one. Is there a way to do it without drawing it again?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yup, edit the layer you want the polygon from by clicking on the 'pencil' icon. Then select **Copy features** icon (in the red circle shown) or from the *Edit* Toolbar. Select the layer you want the polygon to be moved to and select the **Paste features** icon (or from *Edit* menu).

To move the polygon, select **Move features** shown in the blue circle or (you guessed it!) from the *Edit Toolbar*.

Hope this helps!

[image: Editing]

Answer (score 6):

1. make layers editable
2. select items on the source layer
3. cut to clipboard: **Ctrl+X**
4. go to destination layer
5. paste from clipboard: **Ctrl+V**

Comment: Glad you mentioned keyboard shortcuts, much easier than finding and clicking the relevant menu options and icons!